Prompts for LLava running on Ollama
I am just starting to learn how to use LLMs. For starters I have installed Ollama on a PC and pull some models, one of them being LlaVA.
Then I use the method described here with curl to run a query:
curl http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{
  "model": "llava",
  "prompt":"What is in this picture?",
  "images": ["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"]
}'

It is working well to some extend.
However I have recently learned about prompts and the way they influence the results of the queries on LLMs.
For some models like Llama2 the prompts are quite special (as written here) containing tags like [INST] or <<SYS>>
So I am wondering:

Does Llava have this kind of structured prompt scheme?
And more importantly, how can I engineer the prompt when using Llava with Ollama?

Should I just get a string version of the prompt and pass it to the prompt in the curl instruction?
I believe langchain has some functions to generate prompts, and I wonder if they can be used too
